# How to shutdown the oracle database inside a docker container?

Tags: oracle, docker

I run Oracle Database 12.2.0.1 from [official dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile). As far as I see, if I do

```
docker stop <container_id>
```

the current state of the database is lost and next time it will do some clean start.

How to shutdown the database correctly and stop the container, but save the current state?

If I do

```
./sqlplus sys as sysdba
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
```

the container remains running and still consumes 11GB of 16GB of RAM, so as far as I guess, to stop the container I should probably kill some process, but it is not clear when should I do

```
docker commit <container_id>
```

so ideally I need something like shutdown_oracle_and_commit_container.sh.

Inside the docker container the oracle instance is started with runOracle.sh, but there is no stopOracle.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a docker [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to store the data from your database outside your container. Therefore use the `-v` option and mount any path you like to store your data to `/opt/oracle/oradata` inside the container.

From the [docs](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance#running-oracle-database-in-a-docker-container):

> -v /opt/oracle/oradata
>
> The data volume to use for the database.
>
> Has to be writable by the Unix "oracle" (uid: 54321) user inside the container!
>
> If omitted the database will not be persisted over container recreation.

So according to that run:

```
docker run -v /path/to/your/datastore/:/opt/oracle/oradata oracle/database
```

The data from your database are now stored outside the container. If you use `docker stop <container_id>` or even `docker rm <container_id>` and you recreate a  container again your data will be the same. For more information and configuration parameters see the [docs](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance).

Comment: Samuel, the data will be stored in an external volume, but how do you shutdown a database that runs inside a container?

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown the DB inside docker container, first

- get into container in interactive mode, by executing:

```
docker exec -it <name> /bin/bash
```

if you made it with default name, <name> = myxedb

- start sqlplus and login to your DB (as sysdba)

```
sqlplus /nolog
conn sys/***@<db> as sysdba
```

in my case, <db> = //localhost:1521/XE

- issue the shutdown process

```
shutdown immediate
```

That's it.

Comment: How do you startup that database again? 

I'm trying to follow the instructions to enable MAX_STRING_SIZE for extended data types and collation. 
"3. Shut down the CDB"  `SHUTDOWN;`
`ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor`
"4. Restart the CDB in UPGRADE mode"  `startup upgrade;`
`SQL> STARTUP UPGRADE;
SP2-0640: Not connected
`